# How to sort by type and then by modified in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, files, filemanager

How to automatically sort by type and then by modified in file manager?

Using 13.04 and Gnome 3.8

Comment: To clarify, when I sort by "type", the folders are on top with the files listed below. The folders and files are then arranged in alphabetical order or by "name". I want this secondary sorting to be by date modified. So that you have everything  first sorted by "type" and then each type is then sorted by "date modified". How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end.

Click on location options (top right hand corner) and then preferences.

On the view tab select "By modification date" in the drop down menu and check the "sort folders before files"

Comment: This answer does not correspond to the question. Sorting by folderhood is not the same as sorting by type.